# Is the RLP protocol supposed to decode the same values that were encoded?

Tags: ruby, encoding, decoding, ethereum

I'm using a Ruby RLP library to encode one value and then decode it. However, I'm getting different values for encoding and decoding:

```
require 'rlp'                                                                                           

class Transaction                                                                                       
  include RLP::Sedes::Serializable                                                                      

  set_serializable_fields(                                                                              
    to: RLP::Sedes::Binary.fixed_length(20, allow_empty: true)                                          
  )                                                                                                     

  def initialize(*args)                                                                                 
    fields = parse_field_args(args)                                                                     
    fields[:to] = [fields[:to]].pack('H*')                                                              

    serializable_initialize(fields)                                                                     
  end                                                                                                   

  def encoded                                                                                           
    RLP.encode(self)                                                                                    
  end                                                                                                   

  def self.decode(data_in)                                                                              
    deserialize(RLP.decode(data_in))                                                                    
  end                                                                                                   
end                                                                                                     

recipient = "6ba381ce15b19c7e44b8603ad7e698059c09a39b"                                                  
tx = Transaction.new(recipient)                                                                         

puts "Should decode to #{recipient}"                                                                    
puts "Actually decodes to #{Transaction.decode(tx.encoded).to.unpack('H*').first}"
```

Running it, the decoded value is actually `431e51ced80a7685c93b`, instead of the inputed value. This doesn't even seem to be related to what was encoded.

Is the library at fault here? I'm using this library:
https://github.com/cryptape/ruby-rlp

Comment: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idm46227256017920 might be very useful reading.

Comment: Jeez, well sorry for suggesting that other people are fallible too. I supplied the evidence in the code above, and if someone can help to prove or disprove me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is always the same and you can go back and forth.

```rb
require "eth"

recipient = "6ba381ce15b19c7e44b8603ad7e698059c09a39b"                                                  
# => "6ba381ce15b19c7e44b8603ad7e698059c09a39b"

encoded = Eth::Rlp.encode "6ba381ce15b19c7e44b8603ad7e698059c09a39b"
# => "\xA86ba381ce15b19c7e44b8603ad7e698059c09a39b"

decoded = Eth::Rlp.decode encoded
# => "6ba381ce15b19c7e44b8603ad7e698059c09a39b"

decoded === recipient
# => true
```

If you are trying to build a transaction serializer in Ruby, take a look at the [eth](https://github.com/q9f/eth.rb) gem.